# How to use Cognito custom attributes for IAM Role policy template

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam

In a multi-tenant setup I need to limit access to S3 bucket based on Congito custom attribute `custom:orgId`.

Done so far:

- Added custom attribute to the User Pool: `custom:orgId`
- Granted read custom attribute permissions to App Client
- Configured custom attribute mapping in Identity Pool > Authentication Providers > Cognito > Attributes for access control: `Tag key for principal: orgId`, `Attribute name: custom:orgId`
- Assume Role Policy

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Federated": "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": [
        "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
        "sts:TagSession"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud": "us-east-1:3498beea-a45e-4b5a-xxx-yyy"
        },
        "ForAnyValue:StringLike": {
          "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:amr": "authenticated"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

- Role Policy:

```json
{
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::restricted",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "s3:prefix": [
                        "${aws:PrincipalTag/orgId}/*"
                    ]
                }
            }
}
```

I am getting an STS session on behalf of an authenticated user (using Amplify) and trying to list the bucket. I get 403 error.

1. What am I missing in this setup?
2. How do I debug / make sure that STS session request contains `aws:PrincipalTag/orgId`

Comment: I can see that it's working when using ```${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}``` variable

Comment: Please share your assume role policy document. You might be missing something there.

Comment: @AleksanderWons thanks, added to the body of the question

Comment: was you able to find the solution , you can use cloud trail to check the principle tag

Comment: Did you find a solution that enabled you to use custom attributes in a policy?

Comment: nope, still a mystery to me